# GC pause factors

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I have two JVMs, running on two physical machines. Identical hardware, running the same application with identical load, using an identical JVM with the same JVM options, so far as I can tell. Both were restarted yesterday around the same time.

According to jconsole, both have issued an almost identical **number** of collections (both ParNew and CMS) since then. However, the "time spent in GC" on the one is more than **double** the other.
This is easily verified by looking for thread-stopped time in the GC logs.

What (other) factors could influence the pause time for a garbage collection?

Comment: I had a similar problem once. In my case, I was running Glassish 3.1.2 and one of the machines was being used more the web interface of the application while the other was spending CPU with mobile app. There was also an bug in Glassfish JSF which was getting the problem worse. Are you running any application server? What kind of application is that? Are you clustering it or running independently?

Comment: you seem to have more data than we do - gc logs - maybe you should post them?

Comment: These machines are used for a SolrCloud cluster. So, Solr is the only program of significance running, and the query traffic and rate should be equally balanced.

Comment: I've copied a collection from the gc log from a good/bad node here: http://pastebin.com/GskcnWS8 My only real takeaway from that is that it's working harder to GC, but I have no better idea why.

Comment: Those stats only differ by 50%, not 100%, so you probably need to look at the bigger picture, use GCViewer. Also  seems to be a 30-core system, so NUMA? If it is even minor difference can have a big impact. Old gen occupancy is different too, that has an impact on card scanning.

Comment: Old gen occupancy has an influence on Eden collection time? I looked at numastat, but if anything, the "good" node seemed to have a worse hit/miss ratio. And yes, I noticed this initially looking at jconsole summaries, the gc log just served to validate there was a difference.